# Incremental server side rendering Vue3 pages using Vite

Tags: javascript, flask, vuejs3, vite, server-side-rendering

I am currently building a wiki-like web application using Vue3 and Vite for the frontend, and a Flask server for the backend.

Most of an article's page is content that is not changed often, which I would like to server side render / generate on build for SEO and performance reasons. Some content on the page is user specific, so that needs to be rendered on request. Each article is able to contain some interactive features, hence the reason for Vue (otherwise I would've just used Jinja2 templates).

My thought is to server side render the article components using Vue (or Vite?). Then insert it on request that also inserts the user-specific data.

I am not sure if:

**a)** This is a good idea of approaching this

**b)** This is the proper way of doing this

I would like to have your advice.

I have been researching how to do this with Vue and/or Vite, but I am not sure that if I SSR certain components they will still be hydrated.

The only real solutions I have found require me to SSR the entire website, which to me seems inefficient since a lot of the content on the page is rarely edited, and if edited I could just SSR the component again.

Thank you for any replies!